# Reading a text file off of an Arduino SD card through Ethernet Shield

Tags: arduino, sd-card, read-write

I'm working on an Arduino Project and I've wrapped up the portion of connecting the sensors, collecting data for a week, and saving that data. My problem now is taking that data and putting on a website to graph. I have to send data over ethernet for the project so I figured I'll send the information from the text file on the SD card to my computer and go from there with it. The problem is I cannot open the text file and view it in serial monitor. Here is the code

```
    /*
  SD card read/write

 This example shows how to read and write data to and from an SD card file
 The circuit:
 * SD card attached to SPI bus as follows:
 ** MOSI - pin 11
 ** MISO - pin 12
 ** CLK - pin 13
 ** CS - pin 4

 created   Nov 2010
 by David A. Mellis
 modified 9 Apr 2012
 by Tom Igoe

 This example code is in the public domain.

 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

File myFile;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }


  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

  // open the file. note that only one file can be open at a time,
  // so you have to close this one before opening another.
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);

  // if the file opened okay, write to it:
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.print("Writing to test.txt...");
    myFile.println("testing 1, 2, 3.");
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();
    Serial.println("done.");
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }

  // re-open the file for reading:
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt");
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.println("test.txt:");

    // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    while (myFile.available()) {
      Serial.write(myFile.read());
    }
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // nothing happens after setup
}
```

As you can see this is just the ReadWrite code from the example library. It works fine, it writes the data and reads it properly. The problem occurs when I modify it to use my sampledata.txt. It doesn't read it.

Here is an example of a few lines of sampledatatxt.

```
2015-11-25 12:16:10 758
2015-11-25 12:16:12 757
2015-11-25 12:16:14 757
2015-11-25 12:16:16 758
```

Am I missing some of the finer semantics of reading data? Is the data being read too large? It's around a 66MB file.

Any direction would be awesome!

Comment: 2 questions: does reading produce an error message on Serial, or does "nothing" happen? Also, have you tried shortening the file name? I'm not sure but I think you're using some form of FAT file system, which restricts filenames to the 8.3-char format.

Comment: The only error that is produced is the one coded in the setup, no actual error happens. You're right about the FAT format filename, let me change it. Completely skipped my mind.